# Hide HTTP password when downloading maven artifacts

Tags: maven, buildr

We have a password protected Maven repository. When downloading the http password is shown on the console:

```
Downloading: https://arved:passw0rd@maven.arved.at/content/groups/arved/org/apache/xbean/xbean-naming/3.7/xbean-naming-3.7.jar
```

Is it possible to hide the password somehow?

Comment: Never seen this before. What version of Maven are you using and which Maven repository management software?

Comment: How did you configure the http password?

Answer (score 3):

Your repository configuration (URL) is probably wrong, look at this page: 
http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html (encryption is optional)

All what you need is to put password to **$HOME/.m2/settings.xml**

```
<settings>
...
  <servers>
...
    <server>
      <id>arved-repository</id>
      <username>arved</username>
      <password>passw0rd</password>
    </server>
...
  </servers>
...
</settings>
```

And configure repository in **pom.xml** using defined earlier server.id:

```
<project>
...
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>arved-repository</id>
      <name>Arved Repository</name>
      <url>https://maven.arved.at/content/groups/arved</url>
    </repository>
...
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

one way would be to monkey-patch URI::HTTP. The following code could be improved but shows the general idea.

```
# Patch HTTP.to_s so it does not reveal passwords
module URI
  class HTTP
    def to_s
      url = ''
      if @scheme
        url << @scheme
        url << ':'
      end
      if @host
        url << '//'
      end
      if self.userinfo
        url << @user
        if @password
          url << ':***'
        end
        url << '@'
      end
      if @host
        url << @host
      end
      if @port
        url << ':'
        url << @port.to_s
      end
      url << path_query
      if @fragment
        url << '#'
        url << @fragment
      end
      url
    end
  end
end
```